# How to hide Web Reference from another project

Tags: .net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2008, web-services, visibility

I have two Visual Studio 2008 projects which are in the same solution.
How can I add a Web Reference to project A so that project B doesn't see it?

- Project A needs web reference to WebService1
- Project B shouldn't be able to see A.WebService1.* but needs reference to project A
- I don't want to manually modify the generated classes for WebService1 in project A

Answer (score 2):

Well for *Web Referece* I didnn't find any appropriate solution. Anyway for *Service Reference* click on 'Configure Service Reference...' you can set this reference as internal.

Answer (score 1):

add reference of project A to project B, I think that's a short cut if you are not using web sites

Comment: That's what I already do. Project B needs to use some of the features of project A. But project B shouldn't see anything from the namespace A.WebService1.